# Linking front-end to back-end in Django using vanilla Javascript

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, django

I understand that you can use the fetch API to send data from the front-end to your backend to be processed by django views. I also know that you can use jQuery API to do the "fetching of data.

I am wondering if there are any other common methods using only Javascript to send data from the front to the back without using the fetch API or jQuery Ajax.

Comment: "I'm wondering..." questions are often considered not specific enough for Stack Overflow. So, that is the specific technical problem you are trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

I have done this before using URL.

Included something like this:

```
    var binform = document.createElement('form');
    binform.setAttribute('method','POST');
    binform.setAttribute('action',`/unfollow/${data[i].crypto}/`);
```

in my javascript from a fetch request and passing that value to the view function.

```
@csrf_exempt            
def deletecrypto(request, crypto):

        if request.method == "POST":
            user = request.user
            usercurr = User.objects.filter(username=user).first()
            userid = usercurr.id
            profilepic = ProfilePic.objects.filter(user=user).first()
            usr = request.user.username
            following = FollowedCrypto.objects.filter(user=user.id)
            cryptos = []
        
            for i in following:
                cryptos.append(i.cryptocurrency)

            if crypto in cryptos:
                newfollow = FollowedCrypto.objects.filter(user=user, 
                cryptocurrency=crypto).delete()
            
                return render(request,"PlanetCrypton/profile.html",{
                "following":following,
                "crypto": cryptos,
                "user": user,
                "usr" : userid,
            })
```

That's how I managed to delete and in another function, add to my models a cryptocurrency.